# reporting api v4 unique events metric issue

Tags: google-analytics-api

I just want to ask you about the Reporting API v4 because I'm seeing different values between API response and web reporting view (Google Analytics dashboard). The metric is unique events.

This is the query using API Explorer

[API Explorer query screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Rt6a.png)

And here is the API Explorer result (if you want to see the query, read my first comment below, please notice green and red highlighted)

[API Explorer result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFQQp.png)

On the other hand I'm using the web report viewer and for unique events I'm always seeing different values (also I used many other filters, with different scenarios, always returning different data in unique events metric), but (the weird thing) is total events value is ok (in all cases). I used the same dates for API and web view calls (also I applied same filters on web reporting, also I tested using other metrics and the values are the same, so there is no layer 8 issue)

[Web reporting screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wITFc.png)

Do you know what's going on here? I don't know which value is correct, I don't know if API or web reporting is failing.

Best.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this changelog entry - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/changelog#event_tracking and this support article - https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7084499?hl=en

It's all connected to the changes in unique events-connected metrics from September '16 (you can read more about it on Analytics Blog under "*Improving Google Analytics Events with Unique Events*" post).

Right now:

1. WEB UI "**Unique Events**" = API "**ga:uniqueEventsTemporary**";
2. WEB UI "**Unique Dimension Combinations**" = API
   "**ga:uniqueDimensionCombinations**" and "**ga:uniqueEvents**".

Answer (score 1):

This is the query using API Explorer (I posted in an answer because I couldn't do in question, only 2 links allowed)

[API Explorer query screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Rt6a.png)